# OpenTK application crashing after updating via NuGet

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, config, opentk

Our Windows Forms Application crashes after we install a new version of OpenTK via NuGet. The rest of the application runs but forms using the OpenTK part just crash the application when loaded. We include two dlls in our Application, OpenTK.dll and OpenTK.GLControl.dll and worked with two similar versions until now. NuGet provides Updates, but the versioning for the two dlls is different: v3.2.0 for the first and v3.1.0 for the second, which may also cause the error or the need to store the information NuGet puts into the .config.exe file.

We only have this problem after deleting the Application.config.exe, where NuGet stores the following lines:

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="OpenTK" publicKeyToken="bad199fe84eb3df4" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.2.0.0" newVersion="3.2.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

We would like to ship the .exe without the .config.exe file and would like to know if there is a way of putting this configuration into the .exe file, enabling us to update to new Versions of OpenTK when available.

Answer (score 0):

The `Application.config.exe` is created by `app.config` file under the output folder when you build your project. And it works for the application during runtime. If you want to ship the `.exe` without the .config.exe file, you could embed the `app.config` into exe and then remove the default `Application.config.exe` on the **bin** folder.

**1)** change your **Build Action** of **App.config** to `Embedded Resource`.

[image]

**2)** delete `bin` and `obj` and rebuild your project to generate the new output files.

**3)** then you can use your **application.exe** file which already embeds the `app.config` file.

**After that**, you can delete `application.config.exe` which is generated from `app.config` by the VS by default. And it is already embedded in the `applciation.exe`.